# set document.cookie in firefox addon in contentScript

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to set some cookie inside firefox addon contentScipt:

```
// Content Script ( js/firefox.js )

self.port.on("start", function() {
  var request;
  document.cookie = "name=value; path=/;";
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', '/', true);
  request.send(null);
});
```

But when I see request headers and cookies there is nothing about cookie 'name'. 
Is it possible to add cookie inside contentScipt?

Main addon script looks like this

```
// Main Addon Script ( js/index.js )

var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var button = require("sdk/ui/button/toggle").ToggleButton({
  id: "button",
  label: "button",
  icon: "./img/icon/16.png",
  onChange: handleChange
});

var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  contentURL: data.url("popup.html"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("js/firefox.js"),
  position: button,
  onHide: handleHide
});

function handleChange(state) {
  if (state.checked) {
    panel.show({
      position: button
    });
  }
}

function handleHide() {
  button.state('window', {checked: false});
}

panel.on("show", function () {
  panel.port.emit("start");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
self.port.on("start", function() {
  var request;
  unsafeWindow.document.cookie = "name=value; path=/;";
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', '/', true);
  request.send(null);
});
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work either. The problem is that I wan't to add cookie to another domain, and i can't do that with contentScript.  Maybe the only way to do this is proxying every request to main script and do the request there.